# powershell webscrape local HTML

Tags: html, powershell, web-scraping

Webscraping can be hit or miss for me.  What is most efficient way to scrape this locally saved HTML type page?

After passing the invoke-webrequest gets a bit tricky.
My goal is to place the application names(Git 2.33.0.2,Notepad++ 7.9.2 (x64),R for Windows 4.0.2,RStudio 2021.09.0+351,Tableau Desktop 2021.2.3,Accusoft Prizm Viewer 10.0.3.38) into a variable.

I use get-content "path to .html page" -raw and receive this HTML below.

```
<div>
    <form method="post" action="/MDT/12896/Apps/UpdateSequence" class="ajax">
        
<div class="listelements">
    
    <ul >
        
        <li class="corner-all t-state-default t-header">
            Git 2.33.0.2
            
        </li>
        
        <li class="corner-all t-state-default t-header">
            Notepad++ 7.9.2 (x64)
            
        </li>
        
        <li class="corner-all t-state-default t-header">
            R for Windows 4.0.2
            
        </li>
        
        <li class="corner-all t-state-default t-header">
            RStudio 2021.09.0+351
            
        </li>
        
        <li class="corner-all t-state-default t-header">
            Tableau Desktop 2021.2.3
            
        </li>
        
        <li class="corner-all t-state-default t-header">
            Accusoft Prizm Viewer 10.0.3.38
            
        </li>
        
    </ul>
    
</div>
<br class="clear"/>


        <br class="clear"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean like `[regex]::Matches((Get-Content .\path\to\file.html -Raw),'(?<=>)\s*[^<]+\s*(?=</li>)')|% Value |% Trim`?

Comment: Very efficient!  Thank you for your expertise!